# How to use LoadingRowGroup in SilverLight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, events

I want to use LoadingRowGroup event in SilverLight DataGrid to display a group summary.

I have an event:

```
void dataGrid1_LoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
{                        
    // e.RowGroupHeader
}
```

but I don't know how to use e.RowGroupHeader to set group header value. Maybe I should use e.RowGroupHeader.Template, but I don't know how to set a template by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has helped me, I found a solution by myself :)

In fact there are two ways:
1) by using LoadingRowGroup event in DataGrid:

```
 void dataGrid1_LoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
 {
      e.RowGroupHeader.Template = (ControlTemplate)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(
           @"<ControlTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"">
                    <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"" Background=""LightGray"">
                        <TextBlock Text=""Name of group: "" HorizontalAlignment=""Left""/>
                        <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Name}"" HorizontalAlignment=""Left""/>
                    </StackPanel>
           </ControlTemplate>");
 }
```

2) By setting a Style of DataGridRowGroupHeader:

```
    <data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
            <Style TargetType="data:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                <Setter Property="SublevelIndent" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray">
                                <TextBlock Text="Name of group: " HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>                                                                                                    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                    
            </Style>
    </data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
```

The (2) way is better for static elements. But the first one can be used when you want to generate headers in a more dynamic way.